# Accidentally drew something black on my viewport

Tags: edit-mode, shortcut

[image: The problem]

I dont know what I did. I pressed something before I extrude out of tiredness and the black line apeared. I tried to go back with Ctrl+Z but it didn't work.

Comment: That's the grease pencil. You can disable it in the properties Panel (N) or erase the stroke by holding D and right click erasing.

Comment: Thank you, finally removed it, and learned about a new tool to learn and use.